# Convert numeric variable in Time variable in

Tags: sas

I imported a CSV file in SAS and it has a time variable.But the time variable is in numeric format like 515 which refers 05:15 , 1110 refers 11:10 and 2030 which refers 20:30.

I need to convert it into proper time format and then take out the **Hour** from it.I have tried:

new_time=put(time,hhmm.);

The output which i got is like 0:09 , 0:10.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data have;
input mytimevar;
cards;
515
1110
2030
;
run;

data want;
set have;
time = input(put(mytimevar, 4.) || '00', hhmmss.);
format time tod5.;
run;
```

How this works:

1. Convert `timevar` to text using `put`
2. Append `00` for seconds
3. Input as time variable using `hhmmss.` informat
4. Display with leading zeros for hours using `tod5.` format

Answer (score 0):

A Time value in SAS is numeric whose value is the number of seconds.  The display of such a value typically involves associating a time format such as `TIMEw.d`, `HHMMw.d`, `MMSSw.d`.  There are many more.

From [SAS Help](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=leforinforref&docsetTarget=p1wj0wt2ebe2a0n1lv4lem9hdc0v.htm&locale=en) (*my italics*)

> SAS time value
>   is a value representing the number of seconds since
>   midnight of the current day. *SAS time values are between 0 and 86400.*

NOTE: The time formats **will** handle time values (*number of seconds*) outside the 0 to 24 hours range.

For your case of a time value (call it the `csvtime`) encoded as `100*hours + minutes` the SAS time value can be computed using the `dhms` function specifying zero for the `d` and `s` arguments, and the `h` and `m` arguments parsed from the csv time using integer division and modulus arithmetic.

```
sastime = dhms (0, floor(cvstime/100), mod(cvstime,100), 0);
format sastime time7.; * values displayed will be rendered using hh:mm:ss construct;
```